# java automatically doubling array size

Tags: java, arrays, double, capacity

trying to initialize my array at 1 and have it double every time it's input fills up. this is what i have right now

```
int max = 1;
 PhoneRecord[] records = new PhoneRecord[max];
      int numRecords = 0;
      int size = Integer.parseInt(length.records[numRecords]);
 if (size >= max) {
   size = 2*size;
 }
```

but it's clearly full of fail. any suggestions or guidance would be great, thanks.

Comment: ArrayList is similar implementation. use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you should use an `ArrayList`, but several other folks already told you that.

If you still want to use an array, here's how you'd resize it:

```
int max = 1;
PhoneRecord[] records = new PhoneRecord[max];
int numRecords = 0;

void addRecord(PhoneRecord rec) {
    records[numRecords++] = rec;
    if(numRecords == max) {
        /* out of space, double the array size */
        max *= 2;
        records = Arrays.copyOf(records, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting this error talking about the "void addRecord(PhoneRecord rec) {

Comment: File: D:\School\CSC 2310\Book Progs\PhoneDirectory.java  [line: 31]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: D:\School\CSC 2310\Book Progs\PhoneDirectory.java  [line: 31]
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement                               getting this error talking about the void addRecord(PhoneRecord rec) line

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ? It'll exhibit very similar characteristics automatically.

From [the private grow() method](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html):

```
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

You can't override the growth behaviour, but unless you *really* require a doubling due to your app characteristics, I'm sure it'll be sufficient.

Comment: :) honestly this is a comment.

Comment: If you give me time, I was adding additional info/evidence/links etc :-)

Comment: i would use an array list, but it's for a class i'm in and we have to use what he's told us to use ><. that's why it's so frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Size is only multiplying the size number, not double the array size.
Try:

```
            records = Arrays.copyOf(records, records.length*2);
```